# How to merge an itertools generated dataframe and a normal dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have generated a dataframe containing all the possible two combinations of electrocardiogram (ECG) leads using `itertools` using the code below

```
source = [ 'I-s', 'II-s', 'III-s', 'aVR-s', 'aVL-s', 'aVF-s', 'V1-s', 'V2-s', 'V3-s', 'V4-s', 'V5-s', 'V6-s', 'V1Long-s', 'IILong-s', 'V5Long-s', 'Information-s' ]
target = [ 'I-t', 'II-t', 'III-t', 'aVR-t', 'aVL-t', 'aVF-t', 'V1-t', 'V2-t', 'V3-t', 'V4-t', 'V5-t', 'V6-t', 'V1Long-t', 'IILong-t', 'V5Long-t', 'Information-t' ]

from itertools import product
test = pd.DataFrame(list(product(source, target)), columns=['source', 'target'])
```

The test dataframe contains 256 rows/lines containing all the two possible combinations.

The value for each combination is zero as follows

```
test['value'] = 0
```

The test df looks like this:

[image: test dataframe]

I have another dataframe called `diagramDF` that contains the combinations where the `value` column is non-zero. The `diagramDF` is significanntly smaller than the `test` dataframe.

[image: values dataframe]

```
source  target  value
0   I-s II-t    137
1   II-s    I-t 3
2   II-s    III-t   81
3   II-s    IILong-t    13
4   II-s    V1-t    21
5   III-s   II-t    3
6   III-s   aVF-t   19
7   IILong-s    II-t    13
8   IILong-s    V1Long-t    353
9   V1-s    aVL-t   11
10  V1Long-s    IILong-t    175
11  V1Long-s    V3-t    4
12  V1Long-s    aVF-t   4
13  V2-s    V3-t    8
14  V3-s    V2-t    6
15  V3-s    V6-t    2
16  V5-s    aVR-t   5
17  V6-s    III-t   4
18  aVF-s   III-t   79
19  aVF-s   V1Long-t    235
20  aVL-s   I-t 1
21  aVL-s   aVF-t   16
22  aVR-s   aVL-t   1
```

Note that the first two columns `source` and `target` have the same notations

I have tried to replace the zero values of the `test` dataframe with the nonzero values of the `diagramDF` using `merge` like below:

```
df = pd.merge(test, diagramDF, how='left', on=['source', 'target'])
```

However, I get an error informing me that:

> ValueError: The column label 'source' is not unique. For a
> multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to
> each level

Is there something that I am getting wrong? Is there a more efficient and fast way to do this?

Comment: Can you check whether you have two columns named `source` in any of the dataframes? The error simply says that `source` named column is multiple in any of the dataframe.

Comment: I just checked, I have one source column every dataframe

Comment: `diagramDF` has Multi-Index? Can you paste output of `diagramDF.index` ?

Comment: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=23, step=1)

Comment: As I can see this Dataframe has 23 rows only..Can you please put whole dataframe in the question and let me replicate at my end?

Comment: Please check the output in the edited question

Comment: Your code works fine for me. My pandas version is `1.0.1`. May be trying running your code again.

Comment: It works now, I had an older version of Pandas. Maybe that was the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
test = test.reset_index()
diagramDF = diagramDF.reset_index()
new = pd.merge(test, diagramDF, how='left', on=['source', 'target'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Might help, 
`pd.merge(test, diagramDF, how='left', on=['source', 'target'],right_index=True,left_index=True)`